# Regex palavras em minúsculo

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Tenho um Regex que remove os caracteres que não forem letras ou espaço, para uma aplicação em Python. Ex:

```
var = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z \\\]', '', "abc Abc aBC cde123 def-ghi $?!123")
```

Está retornando:

```
abc Abc aBC cde defghi
```

Preciso que, além disso, também retorne tudo em minúsculo:

```
abc abc abc cde defghi
```

Comment: Poderia **[edit]** a pergunta, adicionando exemplos de strings e como deveria ser a saída? Para mim não está muito claro o que deveria ser retornado. Ex: se eu tiver `strs = "abc Abc aBC cde123 def-ghi"`, quais seriam as *palavras em minúsculo*? Entendi que `abc` é, pq está toda em minúsculas, `Abc` não, porque começa com `A`, mas `aBC` começa com minúscula, ela conta? `cde123` tem letras minúsculas mas tb tem números, então não serve, certo? E `def-ghi` é uma palavra só (já que isso é possível em português, por exemplo), ou seriam 2 palavras (`def` e `ghi`)?

Comment: Olá @hkotsubo já editei a pergunta, acho que agora ficou mais claro a minha necessidade. Obrigado

Comment: O método `str.lower` não seria suficiente para o seu caso? Algo como `var.lower()` já retornaria o que, aparentemente, você deseja.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex não faz modificações no texto, ele apenas identifica o texto. Neste caso você está identificando o texto e o substituindo por vazio, mantendo a caixa do texto original.
Como o texto já foi encontrado basta chamar `lower()` na string retornada.

```
var = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z \\\]', '', "string").lower()
```

Comment: Deu certo agora. Obrigado!

Comment: Regex faz sim modificação no texto: é só usar o substitute, default de qualquer linguagem que suporta regex. Exemplo de substituição https://regex101.com/r/JzIETu/1

Comment: Com `re.sub` **daria** para fazer, se o Python tivesse suporte ao token `\L`, que transforma as referências em minúscula ([veja um exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/l1KzUT/1) - tive que mudar um pouco a regex para pegar os caracteres que quero mudar para minúsculo). E nesse caso específico, chamar `lower()` realmente é a solução mais simples, mas apenas para registro, é possível passar uma função para `sub`, que por sua vez transforma o caractere para minúsculo: https://ideone.com/3bjnUL (novamente, a sua solução é mais simples, meu comentário foi só para complementar mesmo)